# Converting query from where not exist to Left Join

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

i am using laravel 5.2 and i have an issue with converting this query

```
 DB::select('SELECT m.*
            FROM member_table AS m
            JOIN treepaths AS t ON m.membershipid = t.descendant
            WHERE m.stage >=' . $usermatrixtype . '
            AND t.ancestor =' . "'" . $firstrightchildmembershipid . "'" . '
            AND NOT EXISTS (
            select user_id from matrix_users AS mr WHERE mr.user_id=m.membershipid AND matrix_id=' . $getusermatrix . '
            ) LIMIT ' . $results
);
```

Here is what i have tried

```
 DB::select('SELECT m.membershipid
            FROM member_table AS m
            JOIN treepaths AS t ON m.membershipid = t.descendant
            WHERE m.stage >=' . $usermatrixtype . '
            AND t.ancestor =' . "'" . $firstleftchildmembershipid . "'" .'
            LEFT OUTER JOIN matrix_users AS mu ON mu.user_id =m.membershipid WHERE
           matrix_id=' . $getusermatrix . ' AND
            mu.userid IS NULL
             LIMIT ' . $results);
```

it returns nothing

Comment: Is it working before you change it?

Comment: yes but very slow

Comment: So in your second query you're trying to match `mu.user_id =m.membershipid` and then at the end you're doing `AND WHERE mu.userid IS NULL` = is this the issue?

Comment: no just edited it that is not the issue

Comment: do you find m.stage column

Comment: i dont understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 DB::select('SELECT m.membershipid
            FROM member_table AS m
            JOIN treepaths AS t ON m.membershipid = t.descendant
            LEFT JOIN matrix_users AS mu ON mu.user_id =m.membershipid AND  matrix_id=' . $getusermatrix . '
            WHERE  mu.userid IS NULL AND m.stage >=' . $usermatrixtype . '
            AND t.ancestor =' . "'" . $firstleftchildmembershipid . "'" .'

             LIMIT ' . $results);
```